# replace two different strings with the nth line of a file every 2 nth occurrences of each string separately

Tags: string, awk, gsub

I am trying to use the following `command_line01` to replace the first and second occurrence of `home_cool` with the first line of `1.txt` individually for each occurrence, and proceeding, replace the first and second occurrence of `home_cool01` also by the first line of `1.txt` individually, and then.., replace the third and fourth occurrences of home_cool with the second line of `1.txt` individually., and etc, that is, every *2 nth* occurrences of `home_cool` or `home_cool01`, respectively replace both strings with the nth line of `1.txt`.

I tried `command_line01` bellow:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} /home_cool01/{gsub("home_cool01", a[++i<3])} /home_cool/{gsub("home_cool", a[++j<3])} 1' 1.txt 0.txt > 2.txt
```

but this only works for the *first two occurrences* for the next two occurrences `home_cool` or `home_cool01` is replaced by *nothing* as show bellow:

```
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree()\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree()\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree()\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree()\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
```

Here my two sources files:

**0.txt:**

```
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tre(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool01)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool01)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool01)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool01)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
```

and

**1.txt:**

```
(food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,)
(food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag,)
(food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, moon, tortoise,)
```

and my desire output **2.txt** is:

```
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
```

**EDIT:** from @markp-fuso comments:

1 - If there are multiple entries I would reboot from second if there is already finished processing the first entry.

2 - If I have more than 6 `home_coool` entries ... I continue from the beginning of `1.txt`.

3 - I would like not to be limited to only two patterns of research, so it should be a proper solution when there is `home_coool02`, `home_coool03` , ..., `home_coool_some_sufix`, but I need to keep an MWE as I posted initially

Comment: what if input is `home_cool`, `home_cool01`, `home_cool` ... do you restart the counter for the 2nd `home_cool` or do you pick up where you left off? what happens if you have more than 6x `home_cool` entries ... do you continue to use the last entry from `1.txt` or do you start over from the beginning of `1.txt`? do you need to worry about additional search patterns, eg, `home_cool02`, `home_cool04`, `home_cool_some_other_suffix`, etc?

Comment: I think you might need to read about the [%](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Ops.html) operator.

Comment: @Luuk i will reading thanks!

Comment: @markp-fuso to your first comment: 1 - If there are multiple entries I would reboot from second if there is already finished processing the first entry.    2 - If I have more than 6 home_coool entries ... I continue from the beginning of `1.txt`.   3 - I would like not to be limited to only two patterns of research, so it should be a proper solution when there is `home_coool02`, `home_coool03` , ..., `home_coool_some_sufix`, but I need to keep an MWE as I posted initially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- only need to worry about search patterns `home_cool` and `home_cool01` (more can be added but will need a bit of rework; likely use an associative array to keep track of counts of each unique pattern)
- replacement pattens are to be applied twice before moving on to the next replacement pattern
- if we reach the end of the replacement patterns we start over from the beginning

Sample input:

```
$ cat 0.txt
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool01)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool01)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool01)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool01)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",          # pick up where we left off with 'home_cool'
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",          # restart from beginning of 0.txt replacment patterns
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
NR==FNR       { a[NR]=$0; n=NR; next}
/home_cool01/ { gsub("home_cool01", a[int((i++)%(n*2)/2)+1])}
/home_cool/   { gsub("home_cool",   a[int((j++)%(n*2)/2)+1])}
1
' 1.txt 0.txt
```

Where:

- `n==3` - number of rows in `1.txt`; so `n*2 == 6`
- `%6` - will generate outputs of `0-5`
- `(%6/2)` - turns output into `0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5`
- `int(...)` - turns output into `0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2`
- `+1` - gives us our array indices of `1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3`
- **NOTE:** yeah, a bit convoluted on the indexing; I'm open to suggestions to simplify

This generates:

```
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, moon, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, moon, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple, sky, cat,blue,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
```

Comment: I'm doing tests for now working very well, thanks by explanation

Comment: Your explanation help me understand other UNIX operations, great clarification..

Comment: I have a new need: let's say that instead of replacing `nth's` occurs from a `0.txt` file pattern with nth's `1.txt` file lines, now I want the process between `0.txt` and `1.txt` only occur until where the second line of `1.txt` is used as output, at this point I redirect the process for another file that contains `home_cool` string to be replaced. Should I post a new question for this?

Comment: although I have understood your explanation about `n==3`, which is something that already seems to fit, but I would need to set a range to which line `x` the command read `1.txt` to make replacements at `0.txt`, and how to make the command restart a new `x+1` line replacement process for make replacements on a third file (say `3.txt`).

Comment: yeah, sounds like a new question , especially since I don't (yet) understand what you're proposing ... so I'm assuming more rounds of back-n-forth ... which would just muddy the waters for this particular Q&A; yeah, if you plan on pulling another file into the mix, adding logic to jump between the replacement files ... definitely a whole new Q&A

Comment: @mark-fuso Yes, I need to express this in a better way, I'm going to take some time to deal with this question.

Comment: here my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69868875/replace-same-string-on-the-two-differents-files-with-the-nth-line-of-a-file-ever