# awk - Replace each X nth occurs from anything between two strings in Different files using line range from another file

Tags: string, awk, line, posix, gsub

I would like to replace each X nth that occurs from anything between two strings, `group_tree(` and `\t`, in Different files using line range from another file.

I have worked in understanding the operation of this issue [Replace each 2 nth occurs from a string in separate files using line range from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69872082/replace-each-2-nth-occurs-from-a-tring-in-separate-files-using-line-range-from) , I have relived the explanations of the authors.

But I have not had success, I still have difficulty in handling the passage where it says somehow `[a[int(n++/2)%2+4]` or `a[int(j++/2)%2+0]` (where, and I know for example `0` means the first line index `1.txt` used to replace anything at `0.txt`, but the other elements are not sure of what they do exactly.

For example, in the line line below that starts with `f==4`, if I set that the replacement begins using the last line of `1.txt` (`index 4`, ie, the `[int (n++/2)%2 + 4]` ), the outfile `4.txt` is does not have the expected content as seen below:

```
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree()\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree()\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree()\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree()\t"
```

rather than:

```
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
```

Another difficulty is that I can only replace the 2 nth consecutive rows of `0.txt`, `0-1.txt` or `0-2.txt`, I can not for example make the first 3 consecutive rows of `0.txt` are replaced using the first `1.txt` line. I tried to do this by putting the number `3` on the stretch `a[int (j++/2)%3 + 0` located on the fourth line of my code below:

```
awk \
'FNR==1 {++f}
f==1 {a[i++]=$0}
f==2 {if (sub(/group_tree[[:space:]]*\(.*\)\\t",$/,"group_tree("a[int(j++/2)%3+0]")\\t\"")) {j++}; print > "2.txt"}
f==3 {if (sub(/group_tree[[:space:]]*\(.*\)\\t",$/,"group_tree("a[int(k++/2)%2+3]")\\t\"")) {k++}; print > "3.txt"}
f==4 {if (sub(/group_tree[[:space:]]*\(.*\)\\t",$/,"group_tree("a[int(n++/2)%2+4]")\\t\"")) {n++}; print > "4.txt"}
' \
    1.txt 0.txt 0-1.txt 0-2.txt
```

but this produced `2.txt` below:

```
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t"
```

rather than:

```
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t"
```

content from source files `0.txt`, `0-1.txt` and `0-2.txt` are the same:

```
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food,hhhh))\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((foodgggggtoise,))\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
```

content from `1.txt` is:

```
(food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,)
(sky, cat,)(sun, sea,)
(car, shape)(milk, market,)
(man, shirt)(hair, life)
(dog, big)(bal, pink)
```

**EDIT UPDATE:**

Output's desired:

**2.txt:**

```
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t"
```

**3.txt:**

```
"car_snif = house.group_tree((man, shirt)(hair, life))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((man, shirt)(hair, life))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((man, shirt)(hair, life))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((man, shirt)(hair, life))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
```

**4.txt:**

```
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t"
```

Comment: I've had my first mug of caffeine for the day and ... I'm not following the logic ... think I need more caffeine; it would help if you could update the question to include the expected output from all of this (ie, show the contents of the 3x output files `2.txt, `3.txt`, and `4.txt`)

Comment: @markp-fuso All I want is to control and manage to generate the  2.`txt` , `3.txt` and `4.txt` outputs using the code posted on my question, for this I must understand and know how to manipulate the operations that occur within the `a[#]`.

Comment: @markp-fuso I'll make the update request, just a while.

Comment: @markp-fuso are three different outputs because the same code must meet 3 different requirements, in the first output the first line of `1.txt` is used every 3 occurrences, in the `3.txt` output starts replacement from the fourth line of 1.txt (indice 3) and is used every 2 occurrences, in the 4.txt output the replacement starts using the last line of 1.txt and is used every  2 occurrences, but on `4.txt` this fail too.

Comment: @markp-fuso edit the update was completed.

Comment: @markp-fuso  for example: When I define `a[int(j++/2)%2+3`  It means that I want the replacement to start using the fourth line of  `1.txt` (indice 3?) and after 2 occurs use the fifth line (last line from `1.txt`) of `1.txt`, and if there are more occurs yet, then start using from the fourth line `1.txt`.

Comment: ok, so you're trying to understand how to read/modify the index of the `a[]` array to perform the desired replacements; up to this point the answers to your questions have consisted of using single-letter variables and short-hand notations to jam everything into the `a[...]` references; in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69867762) I provided a breakdown of what was going on with the array index calculations; you can do the same thing with the other answers you've received ...

Comment: it's just basic debugging; for most languages I'd grab a piece of paper (or open notepad) and start stepping through the code one line at a time, keeping track of how each variable is changing along the way; luckily `GNU awk` has a bulit in debugger to make this a lot easier; for starters I'd suggest downloading [GAWK: Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/) (pick your desired format); then take a look at `Chapter 14: Debugging awk Programs` ...

Comment: from there it's just a case of stepping through your `awk` program and `p`rinting out the contents of variables to see how/when they're changing along the way; at this point you've received a lot of different answers in order to address an ever changing list of requirements; I think your best option may be to get used to the debugger and then go back through all of your recent Q&A's and (via the debugger) make sure you understand how each answer functions

Comment: another standard 'trick' I make use of ... adding `print(f)` commands to my `awk` scripts to print items (lines, fields, array indices/values, variables) to stdout; this tends to be a bit faster than a debugger and as long as I use some descriptive prefixes in the output it's fairly easy to scan the list of output to see how variables are changing along the way

Comment: @markp-fuso really your trick can help track what occurs, I will try to use your trick to come to a conclusion of my question.

Comment: @markp-fuso   really before posting this question I have read and been inspired many times on this question here
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/69867762

Comment: @markp-fuso I have done several tests and it worked at all, your explanation is a general aborganment at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69867762/10824251 and studying this approach I extracts what was enough to solve this current issue, although your approach has more Utilities still. I could post the answer of this issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be the `a[int((k++)% (x3*2)/x2)+x1]`:
Be `N` the total number of `1.txt` lines.
`x1` is the line indice (greater than or equal to `0`, less than or equal to `N`) that I wish to be the first line of `1.txt` to be used in substitution.

`x2` is the number of occurrences that desire that is replaced by the *nth* line of `1.txt`, in other words `x2` is the number of repeated times that I use a certain line of `1.txt` to make replacements at `0.txt`, or `0-1.txt` or `0-2.txt`.

Now, let's say I want to use the interval that includes the `x1` index line plus `Z` lines (`Z` less or equal to "`N - (x1 + 1)`"), and that `Z + 1 = U = (x3*2)/x2`. For `(x3*2)/x2` We know that `x2` is constant because it represents the number of times I chose to use the same `1.txt` line, then depending on arranging `x3*2` such that at the end `(x3*2)/x2 = U`.

At this point `x3` can be found algebraically and is also found in the derived sequence of `%(x3*2)/x2` as in this explanation of @markp-fuso https://stackoverflow.com/a/69867762/10824251 (here it uses `(%6/2)`).

As long as `U` will never be greater than `N` then there will never be empty spaces between group_tree (and `\t` in `2.txt`, `3.txt` and `4.txt` output files, and so I consider the question solved IMHO.

If my answer is very wrong I am willing to correct it or deleted it. For now I will wait for a while and I will not mark as solved because my answer, although it works for me, I am not a specialist, I await a more academic answer from a specialist.

```
awk \
'FNR==1 {++f}
f==1 {a[i++]=$0}
f==2 {if (sub(/group_tree[[:space:]]*\(.*\)\\t",$/,"group_tree("a[int((h++)%(3*2)/2)+1]")\\t\"")) ; print > "2.txt"}
f==3 {if (sub(/group_tree[[:space:]]*\(.*\)\\t",$/,"group_tree("a[int((j++)%(1*1)/1)+4]")\\t\"")) ; print > "3.txt"}
f==4 {if (sub(/group_tree[[:space:]]*\(.*\)\\t",$/,"group_tree("a[int((k++)%(3*2)/2)+2]")\\t\"")) ; print > "4.txt"}' \
    1.txt 0.txt 0-1.txt 0-2.txt
```

Note: Here I used three different variables, as also observed @markp-fuso in the comments. The variables are `h`, `j`, `k` respectively. This is necessary to avoid incrementation overlap (ie `j++`, `k++`, `h++`). Also note that `U` and `x1` are relational, and the value of one affects the other in the end result of the output files, in this case, `2.txt`, `3.txt` and `4.txt` and not suitable values for `U` result in empty spaces between The two strings searched in the contents of the output files.

Explanation:

Line 4 from code: Use the nth `1.txt` line between the indice lines `1` and `3`, `2` times for each occurrence of anything between the two searched strings

Line 5 from code: Use the nth `1.txt` line and in this case the interval consists only by the indice line `4` (the last line of `1.txt`), 1 time for each occurrence of anything between the two searched strings.

Line 6 from code: Use the nth `1.txt` line between the indice `2` and `4` lines, 2 times for each occurrence of anything between the two searched strings.